# Python Raising an Exception within "try" block, then catching the same Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

Came across `try`/`except` blocks, such as:

```
def foo(name):
    try:
        if name == "bad_name":
            raise Exception()
    except Exception:
        do_something()
        return
```

Is there a reason for doing this, instead of:

```
def foo(name):
    if name == "bad_name":
        do_something()
        return
```

Comment: In my view, the first code snippet is an abuse of the exception handling mechanism.

Comment: Not necessarily; if there were multiple points at which an exception could be raised, it could make sense for all of them to lead to a single `except` block where they are handled uniformly. (Sort of like a strictly controlled use of `goto`.)

Comment: This specific example is bad.  But if there were other things between the `try:` and the `except:` that could also throw the exception, then maybe. Even in that second case, you should avoid `except Exception`.  If you know what sorts of exceptions are likely to occur, then catch those.  Catching anything and everything is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

In your example specific I would also not have used `try`/`except` because as you stated, you could just use an `if` statement.

`Try`/`except` is for occasions where you know the program may crash, so therefore you have written some code that'll run instead of the entire program crashing. You could for example override the default error messages with custom ones.

A better example could be that you want to multiply a number the user wrote times two. Since the `input` function always returns a `string`, we need to cast it to an `int` using the built-in `int` function. This would work fine if the user had typed in an integer, but if the user had typed in a `str` instead, the entire program would crash. Let's say we want to print out a message if that happens, we could use `try`/`except`. If we also want to repeat the question over and over again until the user writes an integer, we can use a simple `while` loop. The code below is an implementation of this.

```
print("Write any integer and I will multiply it with two!")

while True:
    # Get user input
    userInput = input("Write any number: ")
    try:
        # Here we try to cast str to int
        num = int(userInput)

        # The next line will only be run if the line before 
        # didn't crash. We break out of the while loop
        break

    # If the casting didn't work, this code will run
    # Notice that we store the exception as e,
    # so if we want we could print it
    except Exception as e:
        print("{} is not an integer!\n".format(userInput))

# This code will be run if the while loop
# is broken out of, which will only happen
# if the user wrote an integer
print("Your number multiplied with 2:\n{}".format(num * 2))
```

Expected outcome:

```
Write any integer and I will multiply it with two!
Write any number: a
a is not an integer!

Write any number: b
b is not an integer!

Write any number: 4
Your number multiplied with 2:
8
```